# python venv --upgrade do not change python in venv

Tags: python, python-venv

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and current default python3 is python3.6 .

I created a venv by: `python3 -m venv /opt/jupyterhub/`

Now, I want to upgrade the venv to python3.8. so I run: `python3.8 -m venv /opt/jupyterhub --upgrade`

here is the current result:

```
➜  jupyterhub ll bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Oct 28 12:11 bin/python -> python3
➜  jupyterhub ll bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Oct 28 12:11 bin/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3
➜  jupyterhub ll /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jan 29  2018 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6
➜  jupyterhub ll bin/python3.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Nov  9 09:10 bin/python3.8 -> /usr/bin/python3.8
```

In my case, the `python` in venv is still python3.6, is there something wrong or it is the designed way.

Comment: did you try reactivating the environment?

Comment: @drum, yes, of course. And I found a python3.8 folder in lib folder which contains only initial site-packages.

Comment: It seems to work as designed. The upgrade adds a symlink of the same name to the python version you upgraded to. So if you want `python` to use `python3.8`, then you can update your symlink by `ln -sfn bin/python3.8 python`

Comment: @drum, sure, I can continue with it smoothly. The only problem is this option should not named "upgrade", "add" is more exact. We need to manually link and freeze & install packages to finish this upgrade.

Comment: I am sorry that you experienced such inconvenience. Feel free to file a ticket with the python foundation

Comment: but seriously though. if you want a more permanent fix, then change your system's `python` to point to `python3.8` then do the upgrade

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `python3` points to `python3.6` :

```
bin/python -> python3
bin/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6
```

And, you mentioned that you set up your virtual env with `python3` command which is recently pointing to `python3.6`.

You want to have `python3.8` to be used in the virtual env setting, so just change where `python3` points to. To get help on the change of alternatives of `python` command see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410579/change-the-python3-default-version-in-ubuntu)